# Set a background color on the HTML <area> element?

Tags: html, border, background-color, imagemap, area

Is there any way to set a background color for the HTML `<area>` element? I'm creating an image map where certain sections of the map will pop up a tooltip when you mouse over them, and I thought it would be cool (and convenient) if I could set a background color for the `<area>` elements so you could see where they were located over the image.

I've tried both background-color and border, and neither have any effect - the `<area>` elements remain "invisible." I'm assuming this is because `<area>` is a self-closing tag and so it doesn't actually have any dimensions? But forcing a height and width didn't help, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can use `div(set postition:absolute)` instead of area

Comment: That did the trick. I just used divs in place of areas and then attached my tooltip plugin to the divs. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: How would the div tag be declared in the map tag after this change? can you paste a sample div tag?

Comment: Surely this would lose the benefit of using `<map>` and `<area>` tags which is they refine non-rectangular shapes for clicking, mouseover etc?

Comment: @user568458: Exactly, and that's why you need to use both <area> and <div> for certain kind of applications...

Comment: An example would be appreciated. As much as I appreciate the time invested in responding, none of the above information is actionable. I have the same issue. I want to create a time zone map, colouring the time zones based on information stored in a database. Unless I am mistaken a div is rectangular, so it won't solve the problem. If I put the area in a div, then the div will change colour but the area won't.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem possible.

You might want to look into this jQuery plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight

Here's an example:

http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html#

Comment: The link to the plugin is down, just redirects to jQuery homepage - the best link I can find is http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/ - looks like the code works by drawing VML in internet explorer and HTML Canvas in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
 $(function() 
 {
      $('.map').maphilight({
      fillColor: '008800'
 });
 var data = $('#id').data('maphilight') || {};

 data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
 $('#id').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
 });
```

Comment: This requires the maphilight plugin below, mentioned in Jason Gennaro's answer

Answer (score 0):

There are two libraries that provide this feature. Both work in the same very non-trivial way - by checking if the browser supports Canvas, then if it does, drawing a Canvas shape, and if it doesn't (i.e. Internet Explorer), drawing VML.

- **Maphilight** as mentioned above ([link that works in 2013](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight))

  - Also includes basic grouping
- [**ImageMapster**](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) (jQuery plugin) which provides this plus other image map features:

  - Scaling image maps (e.g. for use with responsive images)
  - Switching to alternative images within the area
  - Easy tooltips and event binding with lists
  - Grouping

There are some pretty good [demos on the ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html) site.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a title so that when someone hover on it, it gets to know about it.

Example:

```
<area title="amazing" shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="cool">
```

Answer (score -3):

You can give the underlying div an id and then using javascript to change the divs background color.

```
      <div id = "myDiv"></div>
```

and

```
      document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It's just another way of applying a CSS style to the element. The  style applies successfully and shows up in inspect element / firebug, but makes no difference to the appearance. Nor does setting `border` or `visibility: visible; display: block;` etc.