# using jquery i want place an image over another based on the coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to place an image over another based on the coordinates.

My html is:

```
<button id="add">add image</button>
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://www.rangde.org/newsletter/nov11/images/real_tree.png" width="400" usemap="#treemap" />
</div>
<map name="treemap">
    <area shape="circle" coords="345,483,13" alt="Venus" href="#" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="333,361,13" alt="Venus" href="#" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="302,284,13" alt="Venus" href="#" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="79,350,13"  alt="Venus" href="#" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="55,489,13"  alt="Venus" href="#" />
</map>
```

My script is:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function() {
        $('area[alt=Venus]').css('background','http://www.rangde.org/newsletter/nov11/images/green-ball.png');
    });
});
```

[Here is my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/BsPwH/)

Comment: where's the add image code? all you are doing is changing the background color on that click.

Comment: ya help me to change background color

Comment: I'm guessing you mean add an image over the tree that corresponds to one of the image map areas? What is the 3rd coordinate for?

Comment: i edited the question please check it

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019947/set-a-background-color-on-the-html-area-element

Comment: jQuery works, problem in `area` tag.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/offset/ - this will help you. just need to get position, create ne div and change position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an appropriate use of an image map, unfortunately, because they're not actually an element that can be styled.

However, if you switched this over to use some absolutely positioned divs in the same location as your mapped circles, combined with the CSS `border-radius` property, you can create the effect you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/N6Sbt/1/

That should be a pretty straightforward solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, it is not possible to set `background` on `<area>` as it is not a graphical element. If it was possible some would use it earlier to create simple `<canvas>` :)

[Here](http://www.highdots.com/forums/cascading-style-sheets/image-map-area-tag-background-234188.html) is a forum, where people speak about similar

Answer (score 0):

I'll use `<a>` instead of map, which should help you achieve the same thing. Just set them as 'position:absolute' with 'top' and 'left' having the value of coordinates, and 'width', 'height' with the value of size (as it's only 13 pixels, I don't thing rectangle and circle will be that different). Assign them with a class name so you can select them with jQuery. And don't forget to set the 'container' as 'position:relative'.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this plugin it might help.still in development but you can have a look at it.
    http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight
Here is the demo link
    http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_world.html