# HTML: How to add class attribute to area tag

Tags: html, css

I have area code for map in html, and i need to add class for this like:-

```
<area shape="rect" coords="<?php echo $coords; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" id="poplink_<?php echo $units_id; ?>" <? if ($status_units == "sale"){?> class="sale" <? } elseif ($status_units == "was_book"){?> class="was_book" <? } else {?> class="was_sale" <? } ?>>
```

In PHP is print like:-

```
<area shape="rect" coords="<?php echo $coords; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" id="poplink_<?php echo $units_id; ?>" class="sale" >
```

And class is like:-

```
.sale{ background: url(../images/sale.png);
background-position: 97% center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-right: 34px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;}
.was_book{ background: url(../images/was_book.png);
background-position: 97% center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-right: 34px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;}
.was_sale{ background: url(../images/was_sale.png);
background-position: 97% center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-right: 34px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;}
```

I have picture that show all available hose to sale, and i need to add markers for sale house, Like google map.

The error is, The images of class not show . why !!!

Comment: `area` is not generally a style-able element; it's used to pick define a hotspot within an image map. If you need to position an image over a `map`, you're better off using an absolute-positioned `div`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019947/set-a-background-color-on-the-html-area-element (about setting the background *color*, but the principle is the same).

Comment: But the are is in loop and i need for every area some class, some time i add sale, some time is was_sale, So i need solution for it

Comment: I understand you really want `area` to work that way, but it doesn't, no matter how badly you want it to. You could achieve the results that (I think) you want using `div` tags, absolutely positioned, with the same classes. The loop has nothing to do with whether or not an `area` can have a background image.

Comment: i do this `<div style="position:absolute" class="<? echo $class ?>">
    <area shape="rect" coords="<?php echo $coords; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" id="poplink_<?php echo $units_id; ?>"  />  
    </div>` but the icon not show

Comment: You are already using a `class` attribute in `area` element. What you actually want is some styling, and you should reformulate your question (and its title) to say that. Note that there most probably is no pure HTML + CSS solution to the actual problem you seem to have, so you should specify which other techniques are acceptable.

Comment: I have picture that show all available hose to sale, and i need to add markers for sale house