# Given a `<map>` with a background image, how can I color some of its `<area>`s?

Tags: css, html

I have a [`<map>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/map.html) whose `background` CSS property is set to a 400x400 image.

It has a number of `<area>` regions, each of which points to some URL:

```
   <map ...>
     <area shape="rect" coords="5, 5, 10, 10"   href="http://example.com/1">
     <area shape="rect" coords="10, 20, 20, 30" href="http://example.com/2">
     ...
   </map>
```

I would like to color some of the areas with a solid fill color so that they obscure the background image. I had assumed the `<area>` would have a background, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
   <map ...>
     <!-- Adding `style="background-color: red"` has no effect. -->
     <area shape="rect" coords="5, 5, 10, 10"   href="http://example.com/1"
       style="background-color: red">

     <area shape="rect" coords="10, 20, 20, 30" href="http://example.com/2">
     ...
   </map>
```

Is there a way to do this with CSS?

**Edit:** There are existing but not identical questions whose answers take a stab at this, but they either require using jQuery or don't use valid HTML. I'm asking for a CSS-based solution, if one exists.

Comment: From what I understand, no. However, check this out for an alternate method --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019947/set-a-background-color-on-the-html-area-element

Comment: @SRing Hmm -- that answer doesn't seem like it's valid HTML, since the author recommends `div(set postition: [sic] absolute)`, and it's not at all clear to me what that means or where the `div` goes in relation to your `area`.

Comment: The solution presented is to replace your `<area>` with a `<div>` and then use css positioning to mimic the location of your `<area>`. This way you can style your `<div>` as you want. However, I would look at the jQuery solutions below the accepted answer for something a bit more elegant (as the `<div>` solution loses the benefits `<map>` and `<area>`afford. I was looking at this answer --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/18536566/4126804

Comment: @SRing: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll take another stab at it, but I'm really looking for solutions that only involve CSS and HTML; I'm hoping not add a dependency to my whole site just for the sake of this one thing.

Comment: Another option... http://stackoverflow.com/a/5026595/1663001

Comment: @DavidG: Using SVG hadn't occurred to me -- that's definitely a good alternative. I'll try that out!

Answer (score 0):

I sort it out by making an `<a>` with `display=block` and specs. I've just tried to add a inline CSS for bg-color and it worked. It'll be linked (at least so far) but it'll do the job with only HTML CSS.